# Meteor App restricting actions to users

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

In meteor how do I restrict actions  to only one logged in user and the same action isn't available to other logged in users.

Comment: you need roles for that. there are already packages if you want to use. check on atmospherejs.com

Comment: Like which package exactly

Comment: whichever works for you. pick first one if you have no idea

Comment: A common package for using roles is [https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles].